# How to remove WindowsPath and parantheses from a string

Tags: python, regex, string, split, strip

I need to remove `WindowsPath(` and some of the closing parentheses `)` from a directory string.

```
x= (WindowsPath('D:/test/1_birds_bp.png'),WindowsPath('D:/test/1_eagle_mp.png'))
```

What I need to have is

```
x= ('D:/test/1_birds_bp.png', 'D:/test/1_eagle_mp.png')
```

I don't know how to do multiple strings at once.

by following @MonkeyZeus I tried;

```
y = [re.sub("(?<=WindowsPath\(').*?(?='\))",'',a) for  a in x]
```

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: What you show here is not a string, but a tuple of two `WindowsPath` objects. If your question is "how to convert these objects to strings" then the answer is: `x = [ str(e) for e in x]`

Comment: @Błotosmętek nope my question is how to remove them.

Comment: @anubhava Ok please see the OP!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily target the paths with:

```
(?<=WindowsPath\(').*?(?='\))
```

- `(?<=WindowsPath\(')` - left side needs to literally be `WindowsPath('`
- `.*?` - lazily capture everything until we hit the positive lookahead
- `(?='\))` - positive lookahead for literally `')`

https://regex101.com/r/GrIY4I/1/

Comment: could you add how do apply apply to the x ?

Answer (score 1):

```
x= "(WindowsPath('D:/test/1_birds_bp.png'),WindowsPath('D:/test/1_eagle_mp.png'))"

x.replace('WindowsPath(','').replace('(','').replace(')','')
```

output:

```
'D:/test/1_birds_bp.png','D:/test/1_eagle_mp.png'
```

Comment: Can you match the expected output ?